# Creating the fatJar task in doLast in gradle

Tags: gradle

I have got one situation which needs fat jar task to created in doLast and copy the jar in one of the folder. For this, I have written the below task.

task config{

```
doLast {
    clean 
task createFatJar(type: Jar) {
manifest {
    attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'myProjecrt Jar File',  
        'Implementation-Version': version,
        'Main-Class': 'com.bitwise.MyApplication'
}
baseName = project.name
from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
zip64 true
with jar
}
//copy to deployment
def inputdir = file("${buildDir}/libs/qualidi-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar")
def dest = file("C:\\MyFolder\\SubFolder")
copy {
   from inputdir
    into dest
}  
}
```

}
if i create the createFatJar task seprately and execute it it works fine,but in do last it creates the 1 kb file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add below in build.gradle and it should create fat jar in gradle build command

```
jar {
 from {
    (configurations.runtime).collect {
        it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
    }
}
}
```